# Angular Servicer Worker error , Unexpected tokenat Driver.onPush (ngsw-worker.js:2023)

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Hello i'm using Angular Service worker to send notification on my web but when i'm try to send the notification with web push comand in the browser i'm getting  a json error
ngsw-worker.js:2023 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 1
    at Driver.onPush (ngsw-worker.js:2023)
    at ngsw-worker.js:1913

web-push send-notification --endpoint="https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/e8p-BuHFC6E:APA91bHdSY408RYfoNYfPepyPQRgmEDuCTzHOPVQ44tg33vTuYOQafCejxG28SOpkZJn6kMMyUVCAB_imJAc_35Yy4WQuoyDYAeUPOcrzzlWfXe0Ws0TQ_z_ynvKL_bGfnobZTT7EtWB" --key="xxxxxxxxx" --auth="xxxxxxxx" --payload='{data:"asdasda"}' --vapid-subject="mailto:e@yoin.org" --vapid-pubkey= --vapid-pvtkey=

i dont know what i doing wrong if is the payload format or something else

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Matias
This is due to nsgsw-worker.js not communicating with ngsw.json correctly . Please check your ngsw.json again. If this not works , send your ngsw.json .You can take help from https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-service-worker/ OR this should be something like

```
{
    "index": "/index.html",
    "assetGroups": [{
            "name": "app",
            "installMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": [
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/index.html",
                    "/*.css",
                    "/*.js"
                ]
            }
        }, {
            "name": "assets",
            "installMode": "lazy",
            "updateMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": [
                    "/assets/**"
                ]
            }
        }, {
            "buildOptimizer": true,
            "serviceWorker": true,
            "ngswConfigPath": "src/ngsw-config.json",
            "fileReplacements": [{
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }]
        }

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Anil 
thanks for answering, i use that tutorial to guide me this is my ngsw-config.json

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
    "index": "/index.html",
    "assetGroups": [
        {
            "name": "app",
            "installMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": [
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/index.html",
                    "/*.css",
                    "/*.js",
                    "/assets/*"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "assets",
            "installMode": "lazy",
            "updateMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": [
                    "/assets/**",
                    "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "dataGroups": [
        {
            "name": "api-freshness",
            "urls": [
                "/Notification"
            ],
            "cacheConfig": {
                "maxSize": 100,
                "maxAge": "3d",
                "timeout": "1m",
                "strategy": "freshness"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

if a send a null message it return another error i dont know if the scructure of the payload is rigth

[image]

```
   let payLoad = {
  "notification": {
    "title": "The push notification title",
    "actions": [
      {
        "action": "actionOne",
        "title": "Action One"
      }
    ],
    "body": "The is the body which will be shown on notification",
    "dir": "auto",
    "icon": "path to icon",
    "badge": "path to badge",
    "lang": "en",
    "renotify": true,
    "requireInteraction": true,
    "tag": 926796012340920300,
    "vibrate": [300, 100, 400],
    "data": {
      // this object can contain arbitrary info
    }
  }
}
```